# I want the input to be stored in an array and print the string of that specific int in a line

Tags: java

I want the integer to be stored in an array and then once the user enters 0 the while loop will stop and print the contents of the array in string format.

I tried things with the area but quite honestly I do not understand them.

```
public static void apples() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your integer: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    int[] array = {};

    while(number != 0) {
        if(number == 1){
            System.out.println("0");
        }
        else if (number == 3) {
            System.out.println("f");
        }
        else if (number == 5) {
            System.out.println("-l");
        }
        else if (number == 7) {
            System.out.println("V");
        }
        else if (number == 9) {
            System.out.println("-/");
        }
        else if (number == 11) {
            System.out.println("()");
        }
        else if (number == 13) {
            System.out.println("()");
        }
        else if (number == 15) {
            System.out.println("^");
        }
        else if (number == 17) {
            System.out.println("E");
        }
        else if (number == 19) {
            System.out.println("=");
        }
        else if (number == 21) {
            System.out.println("x");
        }
        else if (number == 23) {
            System.out.println("y");
        }
        System.out.println("int: " +  number);
    }
};
```

My expected results would be for the input 135
and the output be 0f-l

Comment: Where do you save the number?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this simple example of usage of `Map` and `List`.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(0, "");
        map.put(1, "0");
        map.put(3, "f");
        map.put(5, "-1");
        map.put(7, "V");
        map.put(9, "-/");
        map.put(11, "()");
        map.put(13, "()");
        map.put(15, "^");
        map.put(17, "E");
        map.put(19, "=");
        map.put(21, "x");
        map.put(23, "y");
        List<Integer> listOfInputIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int integer;

        do {
            System.out.print("Input your next number:");
            integer = input.nextInt();
            listOfInputIntegers.add(integer);

        } while (integer != 0);
        for (int i : listOfInputIntegers) {
            System.out.print(map.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: This is the better way to go.  This would allow you to easily check for bad input with `if (!map.containsKey(i))` and report an error instead of throwing a "no such key" exception.  You should always check for unexpected input values and deal with them appropriately.

Comment: Agree. Exception checking could be implemented in various ways with it and one of it would be (!map.containsKey(integer)). @Steve

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes sense I appreciate your help

Comment: Oops...yeah, I meant 'integer' rather than 'i'.

Comment: One other small suggestion.  I think it cleans up your code to define your static data outside of main().  You could do this by declaring **map** above **main()** as a static variable, and then put the adding of the items in a **static {}** block. - nothing really wrong with the way @MS90 did it though.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the integer to string mappings in a [java.util.Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to easy get the corresponding string after the user types the int. If the typed `int` has a corresponding string add it to the list of strings to be printed at the end. If the typed `int` does not have a corresponding string then print it and ask for next `int`

After the user types in 0 stop the loop, make a string out of the list of strings accumulated until the user typed 0 by joining all the strings from the list

```
public class Test {

    private static Map<Integer, String> integerToStringMappings = new HashMap<>();

    static {
        integerToStringMappings.put(1, "0");
        integerToStringMappings.put(3, "f");
        integerToStringMappings.put(5, "-l");
        .... // and so on for all the integers mapped to strings
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
        Integer number = input.nextInt();

        while(number != 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter your integer: ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            String correspondingString = integerToStringMappings.get(number);

            if ( correspondingString == null ) {
                System.out.println("int: " +  number);
            } else {
                strings.add(correspondingString);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(String.join("", strings));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha!  I didn't see this until I made a similar comment on the first answer.  So @ValentinCarnu demonstrates my suggestion here.

Comment: This also deals with the bad input case.  Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily accomplished by using an ArrayList since you do not know how big the array will be (unless you specifically ask the user for the number of items they will be entering).

After collecting the user's numbers, just loop through each one in the ArrayList to produce the corresponding output using your if-else statements. I highly advise using a switch statement in this case.

```
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int number = input.nextInt();
while(number != 0) {
    values.add(number);
    number = input.nextInt();
}

for(int i=0; i<values.size(); i++) {
    int numberCheck = values.get(i);
    //Run through the if-else statements using numberCheck
    System.out.println("int: " + numberCheck);
}
```